# AutoPlay music and video in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

I have 2 `recycler view` inside a fragment. 1st scroll vertically and 2nd scroll horizontal inside 1st one.(Just like instagram app).  And recycler view display one item at a time and I am using `PagerSnapHelper` to scroll one item at time. `In 2nd recycler view, I am displaying an image and playing a song from url`. And I want to auto play song after scrolling to next/previous item(horizontal an vertical) both. When user click on image than song stop and if click again than song start again.

I wanted same logic for video player too after completing song playing work.

Here, I am facing issues in auto play song. `Sometime song is playing for next item instead of current visible item.` Some time song and image both working fine and than after next scroll suddenly song started playing from next item which not visible yet. And `if user click on image than song stop and when click again than song is playing properly`

I logged and check position number inside `onBindViewHolder` for 1st recycler view and it is logging 2 times. For current scrolled one and for next item too.
I tried many different ways to fix it like

setting recyclable to false `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`
getting position from `holder.getLayoutPosition()`
using `interfaces` etc but count's figure it out.

> Note: I am passing `MediaPlayer` from MainActivity to Fregment to 1st
> recycler view to 2nd recycler view where song is playing.

This is my main codes structure

FragMent:

```
    homeViewVerticalAdapter = new HomeViewVerticalAdapter(getActivity(), verticalDataModals, mp, ...)
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    infiniteScrollListener = new InfiniteScrollListener(linearLayoutManager, this);
    infiniteScrollListener.setLoaded();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    homeViewVerticalAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
    
    // to disable caching so auto song play on all items 
    recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
    
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeViewVerticalAdapter);
```

I logged inside `recyclerView.addOnScrollListener` and inside `public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {` 2 logs are displaying.

1st recycler view(Vertical Scroll)

```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewVerticalAdapter.HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
      final VerticalDataModal verticalDataModal = verticalDataModalList.get(position);
      HomeViewHorizontalAdapter homeViewHorizontalAdapter = null;
      homeViewHorizontalAdapter = new HomeViewHorizontalAdapter(context, postViewItem, mp, ...)
      holder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
      SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
      holder.recyclerView.setOnFlingListener(null);
      snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(holder.recyclerView);
      homeViewHorizontalAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
      holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
      holder.recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().clear();
      holder.recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
      holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(homeViewHorizontalAdapter);
      homeViewHorizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      ......
      ....
    }
  }
```

2st recycler view(Horizontal Scroll)

```
    @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HomeViewHorizontalAdapter.HomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
        String musicPath = horizontalData1modal.getMusicUrl();
        String imagePath = horizontalData1modal.getImageUrl();
        
        Picasso.get()
            .load(imagePath)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.influencers)
            .error(R.drawable.influencers)
            .into(holder.imagePreviewLocal);

        // playing fine when click on layout
        holder.contentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              musicPlayer(musicPath, "click", holder);
            }
        });
        // not playing from auto play
        musicPlayer(musicPath, "auto", holder);
      
       ......
       ....
      }
   }
```

and musing play method inside 2st recycler view(Horizontal Scroll):

Note: Here music playing, loader and hide a layout after some time logic

```
    private void musicPlayer(String musicPath, String playType, @NonNull HomeViewHorizontalAdapter.HomeViewHolder holder) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "music player detected: "+playType);
        holder.contentDataLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(timerMusicTrack != null){
            timerMusicTrack.cancel();
        }
        if ((!mediaplayer.isPlaying() || playType.equals("auto")) && musicPath != null && !musicPath.equals("")) {
            isPlaying = true;
            mediaplayer.reset();
            mediaplayer.stop();
            mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            Uri musicUri = Uri.parse(musicPath);
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(context, musicUri);
            mediaplayer.prepareAsync();
            progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mediaplayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END){
                                progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return true;
                            } else if(what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START){
                                progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mediaplayer.start();
                    timerMusicTrack = new CountDownTimer(delayMillis, 100) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            timerUsed = true;
                            holder.contentDataLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    };
                    timerMusicTrack.start();
                }
            });
        } else {
            isPlaying = false;
            mediaplayer.reset();
            mediaplayer.stop();
            progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        progressBarLocal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

How can I auto play song for currently visible item ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: have u got any solution ? I am also facing the same problem

Comment: @xaif Not the best one but managed to fix it for a while.